# Azure databricks related virtual network

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

You can deploy azue databricks cluster with a virtual network (vnet) in order to control the ip addesses and the access to your cluster via network security group (NSG).

My question is, How can I view the vnet what is binded to my databricks cluster? I have deployed many of then and I can see the relation beetween vnet and NSG but not beetween databricks cluster and vnet.

I would like to know the relations beetween NSG, VNET and cluster, but i can not find the vnet and databricks cluster relation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default deployment of Azure Databricks is a fully managed service on Azure: all data plane resources are deployed to a locked resource group. You can find the **managed resource group** from Azure Databricks Service->Overview->managed resource group on the Azure portal. Click the managed resource group, you will see the workers-vnet, NSG, and storage account associated with your clusters.

If you deploy Azure Databricks data plane resources in your **own virtual network** (sometimes called VNet injection). The custom virtual network must include two subnets dedicated to Azure Databricks. When a cluster is started in the virtual network, a Network Interface is created between the workers-vnet in the managed resource group and the "hub" virtual network. Once a cluster is running, you will see the related resources attached to your custom public or private subnet. Then you could find which VNet\subnet associated with your cluster from these resources overview.

[image]

Read the details about [Quickstart: Create an Azure Databricks workspace in a Virtual Network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-databricks/quickstart-create-databricks-workspace-vnet-injection).

Comment: Thanks, its ok, if you starts the cluster is posible to see the related vnet in the managed resoure group in the Network Interface Object. You can see the private Ip address and the virtual network/subnet .

Comment: glad to help.:)